# «Глубоко пополам»

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, словосочетания, окказионализмы

Впервые *услышала* это выражение в телепередаче. Нашлось оно у этого же ведущего и в печатных изданиях.

*И тихий голос человека, которому **глубоко пополам**, сколько у тебя каратов и сколько нулей на личном счете, произносит: «Зайди-ка».*
[В. Соловьев. Русская тройка (сборник)](https://books.google.ee/books?id=UPP4DAAAQBAJ&pg=PT637&lpg=PT637&dq=%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC&source=bl&ots=fI4VwQsSmU&sig=ACfU3U2EWQl8wMNCVnpCzsak5fzpCysrpQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidgqLFq63hAhUj_SoKHdG4AwgQ6AEwCnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC&f=false)

*Потому-то нам **глубоко пополам**, какие пенсионные планы нам предлагают.*
[В. Соловьев. Разрыв шаблона](https://books.google.ee/books?id=dy_CCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT70&lpg=PT70&dq=%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC&source=bl&ots=Lee5LcCLZj&sig=ACfU3U1qb2_IsqezvlJ_-B1gt-qfBGpMKA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidgqLFq63hAhUj_SoKHdG4AwgQ6AEwCXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC&f=false)

Хотелось бы знать ваше мнение по поводу этого выражения:
как оно образовалось, каково его значение и статус?

Answer (score 2):

**ПОПОЛАМ** жарг., в знач. сказуемого всё равно, безразлично ◆ Мне это пополам. [https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/пополам](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC)

Пополам, надвое, глубоко пополам — это значит ***всё равно***.

Answer (score 2):

Можно предположить, что это словосочетание появилось на замену более вульгарному *пофиг/пофигам*, с которым оно *созвучно*, — по аналогии с *блином* и *ёлками-палками*.

По передаче г-на Соловьёва можно изучать мутационные явления в русском языке — в ней много агрессивной политической риторики и неформальных выражений от посетителей и самого ведущего. Вероятно, оттуда же получило развитие ненормативное употребление выражения "в том числе", которое участники успевают употребить по нескольку раз в одном предложении.

Comment: Я думаю, что здесь скорее такая взаимосвязь выражений: всё равно — всё поровну — всё пополам — пополам  —  глубоко пополам.  Всё равно — это нейтральная речь, а люди хотят выразиться ярко, эффектно. Другое дело,  что такие выражения долго не задерживаются в языке.   Именно вследствие своей излишней  яркости и заметности они быстро устаревают в породившей их среде и уходят на периферию.

Comment: Слишком длинная для буквального смысла цепочка - как в старом анекдоте про "рыбоньку" :). "Глубоко" может идти от устойчивого "глубоко наплевать".

Comment: Цепочка на самом деле очень короткая: равное получается, когда что-то делишь пополам. Всё остальное - детали, без которых можно обойтись. А что за анекдот?

Comment: "Равно" и "поровну" - это деление на _произвольное_ количество равных частей, а пополам - дальнейшая  конкретизация количества. Самое простое (исходное) выражение "двух частей" - в выражении "бабушка _надвое_ сказала".

Comment: Тема одна и та же. Если вам предлагают два варианта, вы говорите "мне пополам". Если их больше, то  надо сказать "мне всё равно" (для меня они все равны).

Comment: Я думаю, что _Alexander_ имел в виду вот этот анекдот: https://books.google.ee/books?id=W8lFBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT129&lpg=PT129&dq=%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=DZDtr_0jNR&sig=ACfU3U3GJSJg42nI2pxQR8A6a66fCT8lvg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQqvSroa_hAhWDs4sKHTqkBhEQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&f=false (Выбрала версию поприличней.)

Comment: @Alex_ander Не могли бы Вы перенести свои рассуждения из комментариев в ответ? (Будет жаль, если вдруг потом удалятся.) И — Вы тоже, как _Sharon,_ относите выражение к жаргонизмам? Или у него другой статус?